# How to calculate the next renewal date of a subscription plan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have setup a subscription plan which will automatically charge the users every month, every three months and every year. The problem is, how can I calculate the exact date to charge the user? We can't charge every 30 days right? Because not all months have 30 days. If we charge on the date bought, people who bought the plan on January 30 won't be billed on February because there's no 30 in February. It's a bit of a complex problem. How can I solve this?

PS : Im using ruby on rails

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could store the `subscribed_on` date and the `number_of_payments` the user already made. Then calculate the next payment date by increasing the `number_of_months` and using the `>>` method on date. `>>` takes the number of days in a month into account:

```
# at subscription date and first payment
subscribed_on      = Date.today # in this example: 2015-01-30
number_of_payments = 1
next_payment_date  = subscribed_on >> number_of_payments
#=> 2015-02-28

# after next payment (on 2015-02-28)
number_of_payments = number_of_payments + 1
next_payment_date  = subscribed_on >> number_of_payments
#=> 2015-03-30

# after next payment (on 2015-03-30)
number_of_payments = number_of_payments + 1
next_payment_date  = subscribed_on >> number_of_payments
#=> 2015-04-30
```

From the documentation of [`Date#>>`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E)

> `d >> n` → `date`
>
> Returns a date object pointing `n` months after `self`. The `n` should be a numeric value.

This does not only return correct dates, it also allows optimized queries for `next_payment_date` and statistics like the average length of subscription time in months.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the >> operator for Date, I will probably have use for this at some point in the future :-)

Comment: It seems to be working well. Can you please tell me what this : `>>` do?

Comment: This looks nice, but it is not clear to me how you handle subscriptions that are charged every 3 months, 6 months etc, instead of monthly. 

Also:
"This does not only return correct dates, it also allows optimized queries for next_payment_date and statistics like average length of subscription time in months." 

Could you further explain?

Comment: @FabianoArruda To calculate the next payment date for subscriptions that renew every `3` months just multiply the `number_of_payments` by `3` before passing to the `>>` method. It is easy to run these kinds of queries against the database because all values (subscription, number of payments, next payment) will be stored in the database, there is no need to calculate something on the fly. Why do I stress that? Because I have seen systems only that only stored sign up and next payment. Calculating average numbers of cycles is harder when you need to calculate the duration for each record first.